# google chrome, jquery statement, need help

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to replace every occurrence of the text "basketball" on any page using a Google Chrome extension with jQuery. So in my content script, I have the code:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace('basketball', 'test'));
```

but on most pages, the site just doesn't load or looks very messed up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not to sure about the google chrome extenstion but there are many ways to search and replace text. http://jsfiddle.net/zxpgx/ is an example of this.

```
$("*").each(function () { if ($(this).children().length == 0) { $(this).text($(this).text().replace('basketball','test')); } });
```

Comment: how do I replace it with an image?